# Increasing speed of a loop where intervals are small and requesting larger amount of data at once

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, pagination

So the code below is suppose to go across canada and grab locations of Circle K.
I am going by 0.0001 due to the fact, city like toronto get dense with the store and when checking the lat&lng go down to 4 sig.
As I run the code I notice that it's gonna take a long time to go across at check 0.0001 at a time for range that is around 42 in just one way.
In addition when I run the code I will get the same locations in chunks back to back due to being 0.0001 difference in area with few stores will not cause any new stores to be discovered.
The combination of repeats and slow grind is where I am asking if anyone has some suggestion to how speed up the process.
I was thinking of adding : &page=100 , to the end of the url but this doesn't help due to the code just out putting what it perceives as page 100,  which does not contain the previous 99 pages.
Is there a way to output pages between 0-whatever pages all at once?
I included the current code I have too in case there is simple fix I overlooked.

So goal, request more data at once and scan across Canada faster.

My code:

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import csv 

lat_lng = [(lat,long) for lat,long in zip(np.arange(42,84,0.01),np.arange(-142,-52,0.01))] 

for latitude,longitude in lat_lng:
  url = f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&services=&region=global"
  payload={}
  headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  print(response.json())
```

Also how the url looks when I add pages: [https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&services=&region=global&page=1](https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat=%7Blatitude%7D&lng=%7Blongitude%7D&services=&region=global&page=1)

I feel finding a method to grab multiple pages is the way to go but have no real method in mind.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the paragraph to be readable. Think about presenting this question to a friend or to your boss. They have to be able to understand what you want.

Comment: If I understand, you should look up pagination in the API you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are doing 4200 request one after another.
I've rewritten your program to do it asynchronously, which speeds it up by a lot. You'll have to install the `httpx` library for that to work though.
Here's the modified Code:

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import csv
import httpx
import asyncio

async def print_data():
    lat_lng = [
        (lat, long) for lat, long in zip(np.arange(42, 84, 0.01), np.arange(-142, -52, 0.01))
    ]
    urls = [
        f"https://www.circlek.com/stores_new.php?lat={la}&lng={lo}&services=&region=global"
        for la, lo in lat_lng
    ][:100] # Only the first 100 urls are requested here!!
    headers = {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Referer": "https://www.circlek.com/store-locator?Canada&lat=43.6529&lng=-79.3849",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "dnt": "1",
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as c:
        tasks = (c.get(url, headers=headers) for url in urls)
        resp = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    for r in resp:
        print(r.json())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(print_data())
```

In my example I only requested the first 100 urls though, because the server won't answer that many requests in a short amount of time. (Read up on rate limiting, if you didn't know about that).
So you'll still have to implement some kind of throttling, to decrease the requests you send out per second. (Maybe do it in batches of a couple hundred and sleep a while between those).

Comment: So, I did pip instal httpx and copied and pasted the code  into python.However, In the output window nothing shows up. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @John_Muir It should print out the json results. Does the program return with status code 0?
Did you copy the last two lines starting with `if __name__ == "__main__":`? They are hidden behind the scroll.

Comment: oh wait its working now, maybe I missed that part earlier. For collecting the data would I just change the spot where it says 100 or is there a different method.

Comment: @John_Muir if you remove the `[:100]` from the end of the line it will request all the 4200 pages asynchronously (instead of the first 100). The problem is the server won't respond after a chunk of that and you'll get timeout errors if you do. So you should split the urls in smaller chunks and probably sleep a while between the chunks. How exactly you do the rate limiting is up to you.